# How do you iterate a list of WebElements using Selenium2/WebDriver to perform an action on some elements

Tags: list, automated-tests, selenium-webdriver

I need to test that certain buttons on the page are being hidden if a user does not have the proper permissions.  I am getting all of the WebElements on the page with:

```
List<WebElement> allElements = findElementsByXpath("//*");
```

I am unsure how to iterate through the list to act on elements that it finds.  All of the examples I find include printing information out, which is not functional for an automated test.

The final goal is to get the list, iterate and do an if...then statement for elements that should not be present with the final then statement including a link that is present and will be clicked so I can assert different text on that page.

Answer (score 0):

This is more less the code you need. This code assumes that you do not change page during execution.

```
for (WebElement t : allElements) {
    if ("button".equalsIgnoreCase(t.getTagName()) && <insert here condition to check if this is the element you are looking for>){
        if (t.isDisplayed()){
             fail;
        }

    }
}
```